# Command behaving differently when saved in a *.sh file

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, echo

I was not able to find an answer to this question, so maybe one of you guys can help me out :)

I wrote some shell scripts to help me automate things, and they work. However, what doesn't work is adding colored text to my `echo`s. It works when entering the command directly into my terminal, but it does NOT work when I put the command into a *.sh file:

### [image: The Problem]

Content of *foo.sh*:

`echo "\n\e[1;37mHello World\e[0m\n"`

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is? Oh, and I am using zsh, if that matters.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

**Update**

Apparently, it works when the content of *foo.sh* is:

`echo $'\n\e[1;37mHello World\e[0m\n'`

I found the answer at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting, which I found thanks to the answer of netmonk. Therefore, I will accept his answer as the correct one. Thanks mate :)

Comment: what is the result of `echo "a\eb" | od -c` 1. when type in terminal, 2. when run in zsh ?

Comment: That'd be "0000000    a 033   b  \n                                                
0000004". Why are you asking? I'm curious. My question has been answered, though. Thanks a lot for your effort, it's appreciated :)

Comment: I was not sure about escape char ( \e ) being properly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it matters! 
The echo command can be different things. 
A builtin command inside a shell program, or a separate and standalone command.

This way, you can consider that the echo you use inside zsh is not the same that you call in your SH shell script ! :)

you should add `-e` to you echo inside your script!

Comment: Note: `-e` doesn't seem to be necessary, it also works without it

Comment: I don't understand how it can work, as far as it didn't worked at first attempt on your side !

Answer (score 3):

When you save the `sh` file you probably prepended everything with the "shell" declaration line, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the code
```

If you want to achieve same results as when you testing it in your shell change this line to one representing your shell.

Comment: The shebang line only matters, if the script is made executable and run as command (`./foo.sh`). If the script is passed as argument to a shell (`sh ./foo.sh`) - which is what the OP posted - the shebang line will be ignored and the script will be run by that shell.